# Can a helicopter like the R44 be lifted up by his rotor head?

Tags: helicopter

I am curious if a rotorcraft could be suspended from rotorhead for an extended period of time.

I am curious about R22 and R44.  I believe I have seen them in the shop lifted up from the 2 holes in the rotor head.

I am also curious if all helicopters have mount/lift points in the rotor head like an MD500C. Would you be able to do the same?

Or are you better lifting from the skids for a longer term lifting?

Comment: I‘m pretty sure all helicopters are suspended from their rotors when flying. Seems to work for most of them.

Comment: @JustSid Bearings can be rated for lower static loads than dynamic loads - when flying, your rotor is definitely not static.

Comment: And if you're looking for the lift points, best to consult the specific aircraft type maintenance manual to find out precisely what to do and how to do it.

Comment: I was just in the R44 and can confirm, it is lifted via the rotors

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you better know what the heck you are doing. :) Whether an individual helicopter can be lifted this way is a different question. You'd have to look at the maintenance manual for the individual aircraft for the answer.

[image: CH-47 being lifted onto a ship by crane.]

Comment: Note the crossbar: The side loads of a crossbar-less hoist would definitely crush the rotor mounts.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Absolutely. Hence my "...you better know what the heck you are doing." comment! LOL! :)

Comment: That comment applies to just about everywhere. And is often enough neglected …

Comment: ...and usually preceded by "Watch this!" in any number of languages. :)